# Is it possible set expiry date of apk android?

Tags: android, apk, free, trial

They sent me an apk with 3 days free, when the 3 days are over I can't use a specific function of the app, is there a way to change the test date so it doesn't stay just 3 days?

Comment: If the lock out is based on local data you can just uninstall/reinstall the apk. If the lock out is based on remote data than your out of luck. Please also read how to ask a question on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This question is too vague and doesn't contain enough information.

Comment: Umm wouldn't this violate at least some policies? You're trying to circumvent a paywall, add more info to your question.